# Can I construct an Object without knowing the class in ActionScript 2?

Tags: class, actionscript-2

In AS2, I can certainly do this:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
```

But is there a way to do something like this?

```
var constructor = MyClass;
var instance = new constructor();
```

This appears to be possible in AS3 by just calling "new" on an instance of the Class object, but I haven't been able to figure out what the syntax would be to get this working in AS2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

First, you must declare the class for include it in the swf.

```
var toto:YOUR_CLASS;
```

And next you can get an instance by :

```
var instance = new["directory.subdirectory.YOUR_CLASS"]();
```

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" xmlns:at="at.controls.*" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;
            private function init():void {
                var obj:Object = ObjectLoader.getInstanceOf(RemoteObject);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

ObjectLoader:

```
package {
    public class ObjectLoader {
        public function ObjectLoader(){
        }

        public static function getInstanceOf(cl:Class):Object {
            return new cl;
        }
    }
```

This is a new example. I create an instance of RemoteObject.
    }

Comment: Is there a way to do it without knowing the *name* of the class either (or, alternatively, to derive the name from the Function object)?

Comment: If you don't know the name of the class. The compilator don't know either. Your Swf file only contains declared class on your source code.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to pass a Class reference to another function, and have the other function construct the instance. This would mean I did reference the class at some point (and it is compiled into the SWF); I just didn't reference it at the location where I instantiated it.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is for ActionScript 3, not 2.